# UWP AppDiagnostic: System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, uwp, access-violation, diagnostics

I am running a windows service (C#, .NET Framework 4.7.2) which manages a UWP app.

Among required features, I need to know if the UWP app is running.

To know the list of running Windows Store Apps, I use the following code:
(based on https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/)

```
private static async Task<List<AppDiagnosticInfo>> GetWindowsStoreApps()
{
    var apps = new List<AppDiagnosticInfo>();

    var diagnosticAccessStatus = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestAccessAsync();
    if (diagnosticAccessStatus != DiagnosticAccessStatus.Allowed)
        return apps;

    var processes = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForProcesses();

    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!process.IsPackaged)
                continue;

            IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> diagnosticInfos = process.GetAppDiagnosticInfos();
            if (diagnosticInfos == null || diagnosticInfos.Count < 1)
                continue;

            apps.Add(diagnosticInfos[0]);
        }
        catch
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return apps;
}
```

I call this method on a regular basis with a Timer. Eventually it will crash the service with the following exception (the try{} catch{} doesn't help).

**Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in ...
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ...**

This occurs when trying to access IsPackaged property.

Why is it crashing? Is it because it's not run from within a UWP app?
Does someone know any alternative to retrieve the list of UWP apps (names and process ids)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We can't reproduce your issue  with above code. Could you try to make a long tick timer to avoid thread block?.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this issue. The issue happens more easily if I stop the UWP app whilst the services is running the GetWindowsStoreApps() method. I am using a System.Timers.Timer which runs the method every 10 seconds at the moment. Should I be using a different type of timer (System.Threading.Timer for example)?

Comment: Have you tried to use [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-19041) to replace?